# Android: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-intent, null, android-context

I am trying to call the `startListening()` method from `SpeechRecognizer`. I am calling the method from a class that is not directly linked from the `MainActivity` layout, but extends Activity and is instantiated by the `MainActivity` class. I understand what a null object reference is, however I don't see where the null object reference is coming from...

Here's the code:

```
public class VoiceRec extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String command;
    private TextView outputText; //TODO:temporary for testing
    private Button speakButton;
    private SpeechRecognizer voicerecognizer;
    private String packageName;

    private RecognitionListener voiceRecListener = new RecognitionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            Log.d("VoiceRec", "onReadyForSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("VoiceRec", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            Log.d("VoiceRec", "onRmsChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            Log.d("VoiceRec", "onBufferReceived");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("VoiceRec", "onEndofSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            Log.d("VoiceRec", "error " + error);
            //mText.setText("error " + error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("VoiceRec", "result " + data.get(i));

            }
            //mText.setText("results: " + str);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            command = new String();
            command = partialResults.getString(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            outputText.setText(command);
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            Log.d("", "onEvent " + eventType);
        }
    };

    public VoiceRec() {
        voicerecognizer.setRecognitionListener(voiceRecListener);
    }

    //for testing with button and output only, remove later
    public VoiceRec(Object...args) {
        voicerecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        voicerecognizer.setRecognitionListener(voiceRecListener);

        speakButton = (Button) args[0];
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        outputText = (TextView) args[1];

        packageName = (String) args[2];

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent vrintent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        vrintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        vrintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, packageName);
        vrintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
        voicerecognizer.startListening(vrintent);
    }
}
```

So the error occurs with the `OnClick` method when I call `voicerecognizer.startListening(vrintent)`. I had this method working when all the code was in the `MainActivity` class originally, so I do not know how to fix this error. I assume it has to do something with context, but I am relatively new to this so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *Only* use `Activity` when you are setting up a user interface, and where you do not add constructors to the `Activity`, and where the framework creates activity instances as a result of a `startActivity()` call somewhere. `VoiceRec` should not inherit from `Activity`. Pass a `Context` to it (constructor parameter, setter method, etc.) for it to use.

Comment: Thank you for  the response. Heres what I did: In VoiceRec, I changed the String packageName to a Context variable and typed `ctx.toString()`. In MainActivity, I passed in the parameter ctx created by `Context ctx = this`. I still get the same error though...

Comment: Have `VoiceRec` not extend `Activity`. This should trigger some compile errors, such as on the `voicerecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this)` line. Replace `this` with the passed-in `Context`.

Comment: That worked! Your explanations are much appreciated